Leaky basement in one corner

Just bought a 3 year old custom built home. Water is leaking into one corner of the home where the floor meets the wall and possibly thru the concrete floor (hydrostatic pressure?) Usually leaks a day or 2 after a big rainfall
Home was built with a Big O weeping system, has a sump pump and has dimple membrane. Soil in my area is very sandy. Gutters are clean. The house is well graded except for the first 2 feet from foundation wall. All downspouts are connected to french drains
A neighbour suggested raising the grading near the foundation and then adding sod. I noticed that the membrane is not tight to the foundation. Should I seal the membrane to the wall? I thought there was supposed to be a moulding at the top of the membrane.
Any thoughts as to what more I should do?

Is this recent? Did they install the sump pump for this issue perhaps? Is there pooling around the sides when it rains?

IDK if it's the entire reason for your leaking, but your dimple board is installed backwards.  The "bumps" are supposed to face the wall (i.e. you should be able to poke your finger into a dimple) to create space between the wall and the flat part of the dimple board.  It should also be sealed against the foundation at the top to keep soil particles from entering.
I'm not sure about your gutter downspout extension, either—it looks like you may have insufficient slope—and possibly a belly in it.
Hopefully the home still has some warranty applicable to the construction.
